# Hibernate many to many selects wrong column

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

SOLVED: I had an error at the place where I called for the getAllergies! There is nothing wrong with this setup.

I'm currently working on a project involving Spring and Hibernate and got an issue with a ManyToMany relation.

These are the java classes:

Patient.java

```
package medicapp.models.impl;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.List;


@Entity
@Table(name="patient")
public class Patient {

    @Id
    @Column(name="Id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="NatNumber")
    private String nationalNumber;
    @Column(name="FirstName")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="LastName")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name="Address")
    private String address;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="birthplace")
    private Municipality birthPlace;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="zipcode")
    private Municipality municipality;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="healthinsuranceid")
    private HealthInsurance healthInsurance;

    @Column(name="Nationality")
    private String nationality;
    @Column(name="ContactName")
    private String contactName;
    @Column(name="ContactNumber")
    private String contactNumber;
    @Column(name="Phone")
    private String phone;
    @Column(name="Email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="Gender")
    private char gender;
    @Column(name="DateOfBirth")
    private Date birthDate;
    @Column(name="Smoker")
    private boolean smoker;
    // Geen Idee hoe we dat gaan doen, effe opgelost door transient te gebruiken, moet nog worden gecheckt

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="bloodgroupid")
    private BloodType bloodType;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="juridicalid")
    private Juridical juridical;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "allergypatient",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="PatientId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "AllergyId")
    )
    private List<Allergy> allergies;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "medicationpatient",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="PatientId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "MedicationId")
    )
    //@Transient
    private List<Medication> medications;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "chronicdiseasepatient",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="PatientId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ChronicDiseaseId")
    )
    //@Transient
    private List<Disease> diseases;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "vaccinationpatient",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="PatientId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "VaccinationId")
    )
    //@Transient
    private List<Vaccination> vaccinations;

    @Column(name="lastwill")
    private boolean lastWill;

    /**
     *
     * @param id
     * @param nationalNumber
     * @param firstName
     * @param lastName
     * @param address
     * @param birthPlace
     * @param municipality
     * @param healthInsurance
     * @param nationality
     * @param gender
     * @param birthDate
     */
    public Patient(int id, String nationalNumber, String firstName, String lastName, String address, Municipality birthPlace, Municipality municipality, HealthInsurance healthInsurance, String nationality, char gender, Date birthDate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nationalNumber = nationalNumber;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
        this.birthPlace = birthPlace;
        this.municipality = municipality;
        this.healthInsurance = healthInsurance;
        this.nationality = nationality;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    /**
     * Default Constructor without parameters, this is required for using Hibernate
     */
    public Patient() {
    }

    /**
     * @param firstName
     * @param lastName
     * @param address
     * @param municipality
     * @param birthDate Patient constructor with the minum required values
     */
    public Patient(String firstName, String lastName, String address, Municipality municipality, Date birthDate) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.address = address;
        this.municipality = municipality;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }
   public Patient(String firstName, String lastName, String address,Date birthDate){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.address = address;

        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public Patient(String firstName, String lastName, String address, Municipality municipality, Municipality birthPlace, String nationalNumber, String nationality, char gender, Date birthDate, String phone, String email, Boolean smoker, Juridical juridical, BloodType bloodType, HealthInsurance healthInsurance, String contactName, String contactNumber, boolean lastWill) {
        this.address = address;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.birthPlace = birthPlace;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.nationality = nationality;
        this.nationalNumber = nationalNumber;
        this.municipality = municipality;
        this.juridical = juridical;
        this.lastWill = lastWill;
        this.healthInsurance = healthInsurance;
        this.bloodType = bloodType;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
        this.smoker = smoker;
        this.contactName = contactName;
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;

    }


    /**
     * @param firstName
     * @param lastName
     * @param address
     * @param municipality
     * @param birthPlace
     * @param nationalNumber
     * @param nationality
     * @param gender
     * @param birthDate
     * Patient constructor that uses all the values retrieved from the e-ID
     * @author Geert Peters
     */
    public Patient(String firstName, String lastName, String address, Municipality municipality, Municipality birthPlace, String nationalNumber, String nationality, char gender, Date birthDate) {
        this.address = address;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.birthPlace = birthPlace;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.nationality = nationality;
        this.nationalNumber = nationalNumber;
        this.municipality = municipality;

    }

     /**
     * @param allergy adds an allergy to a patient's file
     */
    public void addAllergy(Allergy allergy) {
        this.allergies.add(allergy);
    }

    /**
     * @param disease adds a disease to a patient's file
     */
    public void addDisease(Disease disease) {
        this.diseases.add(disease);
    }

    /**
     * @param medication adds a medication to a patient's file
     */
    public void addMedication(Medication medication) {
        this.medications.add(medication);
    }

    /**
     * @param vaccination adds a vaccination to a patient's file
     */
    public void addVaccination(Vaccination vaccination) {
        this.vaccinations.add(vaccination);
    }

    /**
     * @param medication removes a medication  from the list
     */
    public void removeMedication(Medication medication) {
        this.medications.remove(medication);
    }

    /**
     * Gets smoker.
     *
     * @return Value of smoker.
     */
    public boolean isSmoker() {
        return smoker;
    }

    /**
     * Gets birthPlace.
     *
     * @return Value of birthPlace.
     */
    public Municipality getBirthPlace() {
        return birthPlace;
    }

    /**
     * Sets new id.
     *
     * @param id New value of id.
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets new smoker.
     *
     * @param smoker New value of smoker.
     */
    public void setSmoker(boolean smoker) {
        this.smoker = smoker;
    }

    /**
     * Gets id.
     *
     * @return Value of id.
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Gets address.
     *
     * @return Value of address.
     */
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    /**
     * Sets new lastName.
     *
     * @param lastName New value of lastName.
     */
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    /**
     * Gets gender.
     *
     * @return Value of gender.
     */
    public char getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    /**
     * Gets nationalNumber.
     *
     * @return Value of nationalNumber.
     */
    public String getNationalNumber() {
        return nationalNumber;
    }



    /**
     * Gets firstName.
     *
     * @return Value of firstName.
     */
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Gets municipality.
     *
     * @return Value of municipality.
     */
    public Municipality getMunicipality() {
        return municipality;
    }

    /**
     * Sets new nationalNumber.
     *
     * @param nationalNumber New value of nationalNumber.
     */
    public void setNationalNumber(String nationalNumber) {
        this.nationalNumber = nationalNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Sets new nationality.
     *
     * @param nationality New value of nationality.
     */
    public void setNationality(String nationality) {
        this.nationality = nationality;
    }

    /**
     * Sets new municipality.
     *
     * @param municipality New value of municipality.
     */
    public void setMunicipality(Municipality municipality) {
        this.municipality = municipality;
    }

    /**
     * Gets phone.
     *
     * @return Value of phone.
     */
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    /**
     * Sets new gender.
     *
     * @param gender New value of gender.
     */
    public void setGender(char gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    /**
     * Gets contactNumber.
     *
     * @return Value of contactNumber.
     */
    public String getContactNumber() {
        return contactNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Gets lastName.
     *
     * @return Value of lastName.
     */
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    /**
     * Sets new address.
     *
     * @param address New value of address.
     */
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    /**
     * Sets new firstName.
     *
     * @param firstName New value of firstName.
     */
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Sets new birthPlace.
     *
     * @param birthPlace New value of birthPlace.
     */
    public void setBirthPlace(Municipality birthPlace) {
        this.birthPlace = birthPlace;
    }

    /**
     * Gets nationality.
     *
     * @return Value of nationality.
     */
    public String getNationality() {
        return nationality;
    }

    /**
     * Gets contactName.
     *
     * @return Value of contactName.
     */
    public String getContactName() {
        return contactName;
    }

    /**
     * Gets birthDate.
     *
     * @return Value of birthDate.
     */
    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    /**
     * Sets new contactName.
     *
     * @param contactName New value of contactName.
     */
    public void setContactName(String contactName) {
        this.contactName = contactName;
    }

    /**
     * Sets new phone.
     *
     * @param phone New value of phone.
     */
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    /**
     * Sets new contactNumber.
     *
     * @param contactNumber New value of contactNumber.
     */
    public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) {
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
    }



    /**
     * Sets new birthDate.
     *
     * @param birthDate New value of birthDate.
     */
    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    /**
     * Gets vaccinations.
     *
     * @return Value of vaccinations.
     */
    public List<Vaccination> getVaccinations() {
        return vaccinations;
    }

    /**
     * Gets allergies.
     *
     * @return Value(Set) of allergies.
     */
    public List<Allergy> getAllergies() {
        return allergies;
    }

    /**
     * Gets diseases.
     *
     * @return Value(List) of diseases.
     */
    public List<Disease> getDiseases() {
        return diseases;
    }

    /**
     * Gets medications.
     *
     * @return Value(List) of medications.
     */
    public List<Medication> getMedications() {
        return medications;
    }

    /**
     * Gets bloodgroup.
     *
     * @return Value of bloodgroup.
     */
    public BloodType getBloodType() {
        return bloodType;
    }

    /**
     * Sets new bloodgroup.
     *
     * @param bloodType New value of bloodgroup.
     */
    public void setBloodType(BloodType bloodType) {
        this.bloodType = bloodType;
    }

    /**
     * Gets HealthInsurance.
     *
     * @return Value of HealthInsureance.
     */
    public HealthInsurance getHealthInsurance() {
        return healthInsurance;
    }

    /**
     * Sets new HealthInsurance.
     *
     * @param healthInsurance New value of HealthInsurance.
     */
    public void setHealthInsurance(HealthInsurance healthInsurance) {
        this.healthInsurance = healthInsurance;
    }


    /**
     * Gets email.
     *
     * @return Value of email.
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * Sets new lastWill.
     *
     * @param lastWill New value of lastWill.
     */
    public void setLastWill(boolean lastWill) {
        this.lastWill = lastWill;
    }

    /**
     * Sets new juridical.
     *
     * @param juridical New value of juridical.
     */
    public void setJuridical(Juridical juridical) {
        this.juridical = juridical;
    }

    /**
     * Sets new allergies.
     *
     * @param allergies New value of allergies.
     */
    public void setAllergies(List<Allergy> allergies) {
        this.allergies = allergies;
    }

    /**
     * Sets new diseases.
     *
     * @param diseases New value of diseases.
     */
    public void setDiseases(List<Disease> diseases) {
        this.diseases = diseases;
    }

    /**
     * Gets lastWill.
     *
     * @return Value of lastWill.
     */
    public boolean isLastWill() {
        return lastWill;
    }

    /**
     * Gets juridical.
     *
     * @return Value of juridical.
     */
    public Juridical getJuridical() {
        return juridical;
    }

    /**
     * Sets new medications.
     *
     * @param medications New value of medications.
     */
    public void setMedications(List<Medication> medications) {
        this.medications = medications;
    }

    /**
     * Sets new email.
     *
     * @param email New value of email.
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     * Sets new vaccinations.
     *
     * @param vaccinations New value of vaccinations.
     */
    public void setVaccinations(List<Vaccination> vaccinations) {
        this.vaccinations = vaccinations;
    }
}
```

Allergy.java

```
package medicapp.models.impl;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;


@Entity
@Table(name="allergy")
public class Allergy {

    @Id
    @Column(name="Id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "Description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "allergies")
    private List<Patient> patients;

    /**
     * Default Constructor without parameters, this is required for using Hibernate
     */
    public Allergy(){

    }

    /**
     *
     * @param description
     */
    public Allergy(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }


    /**
     * Sets new id.
     *
     * @param id New value of id.
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets new description.
     *
     * @param description New value of description.
     */
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    /**
     * Gets description.
     *
     * @return Value of description.
     */
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * Gets id.
     *
     * @return Value of id.
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Now, if I would call the getAllergies from a Patient object, it will generate this SQL code:

```
select
        allergies0_.PatientId as PatientI1_11_0_,
        allergies0_.AllergyId as AllergyI2_1_0_,
        allergy1_.Id as Id1_0_1_,
        allergy1_.Description as Descript2_0_1_ 
    from
        allergypatient allergies0_ 
    inner join
        allergy allergy1_ 
            on allergies0_.AllergyId=allergy1_.Id 
    where
        allergies0_.PatientId=?
```

This would mean I get these results:

2   3   3   Lactose

2   5   5   Animals

2   5   5   Animals

2   19  19  Pennicilline

Now if I print out the Description of the Allergy instances, it will always give me Hay, since that is the Allergy with id 2.

I need to have the second column to be the column that gets used to get the Allergies. Is there a way for me to change this?

Kind regards

Comment: I dont understand, the second column is the allergyId according to the sql you posted?

Comment: My Apologies, it seems like I had a bug where I called the getAllergy method, but nontheless thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify join collumns with jpa/ which hibernate implements.[Here is an example](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany)

> @ManyToMany
>     @JoinTable(
>         name="EMP_PROJ",
>         joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="EMP_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")},
>         inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PROJ_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")})
>     private List projects;

Comment: That doesn't seem to do much difference, I still get the exact same result